# How could a project use target type object creation if it is a .NET 4.8 project?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

I am looking at and following example code that has the following lines:

```
public static DispenseOptionSketchVolume DoSketchVolume = new();
public static SketchSettingsPageData SketchSettingsPageData = new();
public static BlockVolumeData BlockVolumeData = new();
public static SketchEntityVolumePage SketchEntityVolume = new();
```

In my own project I created a framework 4.8 class library but get the error:

> Feature 'target typed object creation' is not available. Please use language version 9.0 or greater. `new();` is the error.

If I add this to my own csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Visual Studio asks me to attach to a process:
[image]

In the example project the framework is set to 4.8, the type is a class Library, there is a framework that automatically registers the dll and it runs. There is no `<LangVersion>` directive in any file csproj or otherwise.

How could the example project compile the `= new();` statements?

Comment: Humor me. Usually when the run button says "Attach" it's because no solution is open in the Solution Explorer. Do you have a solution open?

Comment: C# 9 is supported on .NET 5 and up. While the specific feature you're asking for is purely a compiler thing, there are too many things in the new C# version that require runtime support that it wouldn't surprise me if the .NET 5 requirement is a hard limit.

Comment: Ref. https://sergiopedri.medium.com/enabling-and-using-c-9-features-on-older-and-unsupported-runtimes-ce384d8debb — an article that claims various feature are (or at least one time would?) work via a manual LangVersion change. (So is then this manual setting ignored / not applied?)

Answer (score 0):

I just set `<LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>` on a large .NET Framework 4.8 solution and it works as expected. The target-typed new is available and no error messages are shown. I successfully tried both VS2019 and VS2022. So it seems this *does* work. Maybe you need to make sure you're building with at least the .NET 5.0 compiler. Make sure your `global.json` is requiring at least a 5.0 SDK.